# How do I parse US date to UK date and return as a date in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datetime-format

I have a datetime which is being passed into a method. It is a US date. I essentially need to convert this to a UK date and return as a datetime. below is an example of what I have tried but it just returns the dateTimeIn format (02/24/2021 12:00:00). What am I doing wrong?

```
    Dim dateTimeIn As Date = #02/24/2021 12:00:00# 
    
    Dim covertToUkDateTime As String = dateTimeIn.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-GB"))
    Dim covertToUkDateTimeToDate As Date = Date.ParseExact(covertToUkDateTime, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"))
    
    Console.WriteLine(covertToUkDateTimeToDate)
```

Comment: There is no such thing as US `DateTime`. Do you receive a string or a DateTime object? Do you simply need to present somewhere a DateTime object in `en-GB` string format? It looks like you're mixing a DateTime object with its representation, i.e., what you see in the IDE, which is presented to you Localized for obvious reasons.

Comment: okay yeah I see what your saying. The method receives as a DateTime object in a US format (from an excel file) . I was trying to convert to Uk a format and then try and parse that as a date but should that not matter as I am potentially mixing the DateTime representation

Comment: @Byronation Using a string instead of a DateTime in code is an error. The *display* of it is where it is converted to a string. The VB way of creating a DateTime with #s needs to be avoided: use the explicit `New DateTime(2021, 2, 24, 12, 0, 0)`.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewMorton. I have managed to resolve this now. I was misunderstanding the way DateTime works with what I was trying to achieve. Thanks for your advice.